# How to add obectID from on schema to another in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, schema

> I'm working on a multivendor cake selling project.
> the situation is the user can customize their cakes.
> to store that in mongo I can do simple post method and add it to mongo schema but the user info(id,name,phone,address) should be there too.
> how can I store the user info in the customize cake schema?

> code I wrote is below.

```
exports.addCustomCake=(req,res)=>{
customCakeModel({
    user_id:req.saved_user._id,
    order_By:req.saved_user.name,
    phone:req.saved_user.phone,
    address:req.saved_user.address
    weight:req.body.weight,
    flavour:req.body.flavour,
    shape:req.body.shape,
    layers:req.body.layers,
    sponge:req.body.sponge,
    cakeType:req.body.cakeType,
    creamLevel:req.body.creamLevel,
    fondantLevel:req.body.fondantLevel,
    fondantCreamLevel:req.body.fondantCreamLevel,
    paintCake:req.body.paintCake,
    fillings:req.body.fillings,
    effects:req.body.effects,
    writingOnCake:req.body.writingOnCake,
}).save((err,customCake)=>{
    if(!err){
        res.status(200).json({
            status:'success',
            result:customCake,
            message:'Custom cake added...'
        });
    }else{
        res.status(404).json({
            result:err,
            message:'Custom cake add failed.'
        })
    }
})
```

}

Comment: What is the error ? Its normal save in mongo.

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')  , that is the error msg , i just want to set it like , if the user logs in and customize cake then the users info(id,name,phone,address) will also be stored in the custom cake database that i created.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the `addCustomCake` on your client? You are trying to access the `saved_user` object that does not exist in your request.

Comment: **saved_user** is actually the schema name that is stored in mongoDB and holds the user info when the user signs up, what i'm trying is to the user will only customize the cake but in the custom cake schema the user that customized the cake , his/her info(id,name,address,phone) will be stored automatically

Comment: `const express=require('express');
const Route=express.Router();
const userController=require('../Routers/userController');
// const customCakeModel=require('../../Database/Models/users/custom_cakeModel');

Route.post('/customCake',userController.addCustomCake);



module.exports=Route;`